# Script to create shell aliases

Tags: python, bash, configuration

Can anybody find anything to pick apart in this script?

```py
#  Copyright (c) 2019. Legorooj

import sys
import os

docstring = '''
add_alias [alias] [command]'''
if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
    print(docstring)
else:
    alias, cmd = sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]
    print('Adding alias...')
    os.system(f'echo "alias {alias}={cmd}" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc')
    print('Alias added')
```

If ran like:

`add_alias bob "echo bob"`, it adds an alias as if you ran

`echo "alias bob="echo bob"" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 4):

We need to do some basic sanity checking of the inputs - alias names can't contain whitespace, for example, and any newlines in the expansion will be treated as the end of the alias definition (and the following text will then be a new command in your `.bashrc`).

The `source ~/.bashrc` in the call to `os.system()` looks pointless, as that shell terminates immediately after.

Answer (score 1):

The script is missing a shebang. (For example `#!/usr/bin/env python`)

The length check `len(sys.argv) <= 1` is not enough, `sys.argv[2]` will crash with `IndexError` when there is only one script argument instead of two. (You probably meant to write `len(sys.argv) <= 2`)

I don't think this script has enough value over adding aliases manually.